# How to hide and unhide a specific ListView item on switch preference on off?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to hide the 2nd option from the list on switch on off, I know how switch works, just tell me how to hide-unhide the option from the list. I want to hide list view item by item position or something like that.

**New query :** Is it possible to add two different adapter and switch them on switch preference change? if yes then how to do that?

This is 100% possible.

```
String [] titles = {"abc","def","ghi"};
String [] descriptions = {"abc","def","ghi"};
int [] images = {R.drawable.ic_abc,R.drawable.ic_def,R.drawable.ic_ghi};
ListView lv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
  lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
  final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), titles, descriptions, images);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
  });
}
```

List view adapter

```
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
  int[] imageArray;
  String[] titleArray;
  String[] descriptionArray;

  public Adapter(Context context, String[] titles1, String [] description1, int[] img1) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_row, R.id.Titles, titles1);
    this.imageArray = img1;
    this.titleArray = titles1;
    this.descriptionArray = description1;
  }

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.Icons);
    TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Titles);
    TextView myDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Descriptions);

    myImage.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
    myTitle.setText(titleArray[position]);
    myDescription.setText(descriptionArray[position]);
    return row;
  }
}
```

Switch preference

```
    public SwitchPreference sw;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_sw);
        sw = (SwitchPreference) findPreference("001");
    }
```

on switch on/off in main activity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean sw = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("001", true);
if (sw) {
  //hide list view item (only one)
} else {
  //unhide list view item (only one)
}
```

Comment: the best is to remove then from adapter and add back on switch, if you want to hide just part of the itemview use setVisibility(View.GONE) in the itemview listener

Comment: where and how to write that? please show me some code!

Comment: The list here: final Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext(), titles, descriptions, images) just remove the objects that you wanna hide from those lists, also it can be just one object cant you do that?

Comment: The second option (for hiding part of the itemview) is from getView() in adapter, set a clickListener that do contentToHide.setVisibility

Comment: I don't understand, actually i'm not a good coder. i'm sorry

Comment: Well, so, first to make it better, create a POJO class that have the tree attributes you want in adapter, then create a list of instances of the class instead tree arrays, with this array you can filter based on the boolean you want

Comment: ahh! it's so complicated I hate list view

Comment: `adapter.getPosition(2);` will that work??

Comment: This will return the element, not the view

Comment: then how? awhhhhh!

Comment: My second comment answered how, remove the items you dont want from the list before creating the adapter. Note: Working with a List instead of a Array will give u access to the method remove(int atIdx)

Comment: aaaah?? excuse me boy! i think i got something `adapter.remove(2);`

Comment: It's not working please do something..

Comment: i did something, see answer

Answer (score 1):

Well, take a look, so you can call remove properly:

```
class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
  List<ItemObject> data = new ArrayList();

  public Adapter(Context context, String[] titles1, String [] description1,     int[] img1) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_row, R.id.Titles, titles1);
    for(int i = 0; i < titles1.lenght; i++)
        data.add(new ItemObject(titles1[i], description1[i], img1[i]);
  }
  static class ItemObject {
       String title, description;
       int image;
       ItemObject(String ti, String desc, int img) {
           title = ti;
           description = desc;
           image = img;
       }
  }
  //plus the rest of your class
```

And change at getView

```
 ItemObject row = data.get(position);
 myImage.setImageResource(row.image);
 myTitle.setText(row.title);
 myDescription.setText(row.description);
```

And add this method in the adapter:

```
 public void removeObject(int at) {
      data.remove(at);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

So you can call removeObject with a position.

Comment: @Shalini: if you are getting an error, then at minimum readers will need to know what that error is. Moreover, remember that you are the eyes and ears on the problem, and we need you to be as descriptive as possible. "It's not working" is not descriptive enough for readers, and does not give folks anything new to respond to. Make your replies as informative as you possibly can, if you want the best available help.

Comment: The error i'm getting is in the code itself, it's showing red.

Comment: Hold the cursor (mouse) in the red highlighted text and see the description of the problem.